STM32MP157F-DK2. Package debconf is not installed
I have built an image for the stm32mp157f-dk2 using bitbake. When trying to install Wazuh, I encountered the following message:
root@stm32mp1:~# dpkg -i wazuh-agent_4.8.0-1_armhf.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package wazuh-agent.
(Reading database ... 19503 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wazuh-agent_4.8.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking wazuh-agent (4.8.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wazuh-agent:
 wazuh-agent depends on debconf; however:
  Package debconf is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wazuh-agent (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wazuh-agent

Could you please advise if I need to add a layer and rebuild the image, or if I need to do something else?
root@stm32mp1:~# cat /etc/build
-----------------------
Build Configuration:  |
-----------------------
BB_VERSION = 2.4.0
BUILD_SYS = x86_64-linux
NATIVELSBSTRING = universal
TARGET_SYS = arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi
MACHINE = stm32mp1
DISTRO = openstlinux-weston
DISTRO_VERSION = 4.2.1-snapshot-20240708
TUNE_FEATURES = arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard
TARGET_FPU = hard
DISTRO_CODENAME = mickledore
ACCEPT_EULA_stm32mp1 = 1
GCCVERSION = 12.%
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = linux-stm32mp
-----------------------
Layer Revisions:      |
-----------------------
meta-python       = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-oe           = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-gnome        = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-initramfs    = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-multimedia   = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-networking   = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-webserver    = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-filesystems  = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-perl         = HEAD:c032fd0b1a9d444711103c2703dfa8e2964a3865
meta-st-stm32mp   = HEAD:931b3f5be2c00f55d114c8f9122082a9d229b776
meta-qt5          = HEAD:cf6ffcbad5275a3428f6046468a0c9d572e813d1
meta-st-openstlinux = HEAD:8c780facff81d3c3878c5fdcd18bdd24fc36478d
meta              = HEAD:20cd64812d286c920bd766145ab1cd968e72667e
meta-virtualization = mickledore:b8db7002764712f2902fe9dea098c171b1128076
meta-selinux      = mickledore:bd3902cb9351c37d8e348abcd95c83d267c0a106
meta-java         = HEAD:ae2952c7668db180fa6acefe82457df913342837
workspace         = <unknown>:<unknown> -- modified


Thank you in advance.
Symeon

dpkg does not resolve package dependencies, so you will have to install them manually. The dependencies for the Wazuh agent can be found at https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-packages/blob/v4.8.0/debs/SPECS/wazuh-agent/debian/control#L11
If you want the installation to resolve dependencies you can use apt or apt-get, which is the way we indicate the installation in the documentation.
apt-get -y install wazuh-manager

https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/wazuh-server/step-by-step.html#installing-the-wazuh-manager

I recommend carrying out the installation according to the steps indicated in the documentation, as you may need to install other dependencies for GPG and obtain the package from the official repository.
If you want to install the package without the repository, you can always download the package using the links provided at https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/packages-list.html
But as far as installation dependencies are concerned, you will have to install them manually or use a package manager that resolves them.
